# expected primary-expression before '*' token?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I can't seem to figure this out! I keep getting an error that says "expected primary-expression before '*' token" with no other hints. It happens on the line that looks like

```
todoList->addItem(QListWidgetItem *taskStr->append(taskQry.value(1).toString()));
```

What does this mean, from what I found by searching it seems to be a syntax error, but could somebody explain to me why it's a syntax error? Is there a better way to attach strings to a list?

```
todoList = new QListWidget(todoGroupBox);

QSqlDatabase localdb = QSqlDatabase::database("TestERP");
if (localdb.open())
{
    QSqlQuery taskQry;

    if (taskQry.exec("SELECT * FROM erp_data.todo_lists;"))
    {
        if (taskQry.value(1).toString() == "")
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,"No Connection","Nothing in the Manufacturer Database\n"
                                     "\nError: " + db.lastError().text());
        }
        else
        {
            while (taskQry.next())
            {
                QString *taskStr = new QString;
                todoList->addItem(QListWidgetItem *taskStr->append(taskQry.value(1).toString()));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(new QWidget,"Not Connected","Connection to the Database could not be Established\n"
                                 "\nError: " + db.lastError().text());
    }
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::information(new QWidget,"Not Connected","Connection to the Database could not be Established\n"
                             "\nError: " + db.lastError().text());
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `todoList->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(taskStr->append(taskQry.value(1).toString())));`?

Comment: That does seem to fix the error but now it says "missing terminating > character". What does that mean? -- I got it I missed a bracket in an include -- i'm an idiot.

Comment: Creating QStrings on the heap is nonsensical. They are implicitely shared, thus cheap to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But this will make it compiled:

```
todoList->addItem(taskQry.value(1).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change

```
while (taskQry.next())
        {
            QString *taskStr = new QString;
            todoList->addItem(QListWidgetItem *taskStr->append(taskQry.value(1).toString()));
        }
```

to

```
while (taskQry.next())
        {   
            // The QListWidgetItem is added automatically to todoList
            new QListWidgetItem(taskQry.value(1).toString(), todoList );
        }
```